# How to do a mongodb search for a string in array of string

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to filter a list of objects based on the objects include a particular string value inside a array of string field.

The collection structure :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b55aabe0550de0021097bf0"),
    "snomedId" : "SNOMED ID",
    "status" : "INACTIVE",
    "clientIds" : [
        "5b55aabd0550de0021097b6e",
        "5b55aabd0550de0021097b6d",
        "5b55aabd0550de0021097b6c"
    ]
}
```

The model class :

```
public class Hotel extends PersistedObject {

    private Status status;
    private List<String> clientIds = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

The Query method :

```
  @Query("{'clientIds': { $in: { 'clientId' : ?1 } }}")
    List<Diagnosis> searchFilterByClientId(String term,String clientId);
```

So in here I want to get a list of Hotels that holds the passing clientId value inside the list of clientId field. But this returns following exception: 
'Query failed with error code 2 and error message '$in needs an array''

Comment: Well yes, [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) expects an array of inputs to check against.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `$in`. Simple find on clientId would be sufficient here.

```
db.collection.find({clientIds: "5b55aabd0550de0021097b6e"})
```

Or in your case:

```
  @Query("{'clientIds': ?1}")
    List<Diagnosis> searchFilterByClientId(String term,String clientId);
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qc9GN2x1Tfx)